# Offline font identifier

Tags: font

I am looking for an offline font identifier for Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, or Ubuntu. Any price and license is fine. GUI or CLI.

The input is an image, the output is a list of font with some associated probabilities. Ideally it shouldn't be restricted to the fonts installed on the computer.

---

For example, the online service ​https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/​ does a good job at identifying font present in a given image:

[image: Screenshot of WhatTheFont, showing the input image of a glyph and four results that show a similar-looking glyph together with the font name]

Comment: Hey, the cloud is fancy, modern and unreliable. Why don't you want to use an online font identification service that may be broken tomorrow? +1, I really wonder why I didn't ask that question before.

Comment: An offline font identification program would need to have its fonts saved offline, which would require you to already have the font you're trying to identify installed. That, or the software would need to be distributed alongside hundreds if not thousands of copyrighted font files.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Maybe such program could be redistributed with a trained statistical classifier instead.